# RegEx for replacing special patterns in a list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I have been working on a python script to tweet some info about my pihole and have came across a small problem. I can't seem to get `re.sub` to work for me like I want it to.

What I am trying to accomplish is taking the output of `netifaces.interfaces()` which for me is `['lo', 'ens4', 'tun0', 'tun1']` and make it look like `ens4, tun0, tun1`

I have tried using

```
netfaces = str(netifaces.interfaces())
netfaces = re.sub('\[|\'|lo|\'|\]', '', netfaces)
```

but it gives me this output:

```
, ens4, tun0, tun1
```

edit:

thanks @the-fourth-bird

i expanded on the regex they gave and came to this

[regex test](https://regex101.com/r/IhReCT/4)

`'lo'(?:,\s*)?|[][')(]|(?:,\s*)?'lo'`

my take:

`'lo'(?:,\s*)?` - searches the string for `'lo',` and removes no matter were found

`[][')(]` - removes all `][` `'` `)(` no matter were found

`(?:,\s*)?'lo'` - removes all `, 'lo'` no matter were found

which also works for the `os.getloadavg()` output that i'm getting as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get that result is that you are matching 4 alternations which you might also write as `[][']|lo` but you are not matching the comma and the space after it so that will not be removed.

If you want to remove `'lo'` from the list without leaving a comma and space at the start, you could use:

```
'lo'(?:,\s*)?|[][']
```

- `'lo'(?:,\s*)?` Match lo followed by an optional part to match a comma and 1+ whitespace characters
- `|` Or
- `[][']` Match any of the listed in the character class `[`, `]`, `'`

Replace with an empty string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IhReCT/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qcnF2F)

For example

```
import re
regex = r"'lo'(?:,\s*)?|[][']"
test_str = "['lo', 'ens4', 'tun0', 'tun1']"
result = re.sub(regex, "", test_str)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Result

```
ens4, tun0, tun1
```

Comment: ended up going with a modified version of yours actually after some testing `'lo'(?:,\s*)?|[][']|(?:,\s*)?'lo'` [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IhReCT/2) will catch `, 'lo'` now as well

Comment: better explanation @ the bottom of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear why you generated that string which looks like a list, but you can use this regex,

```
^[^,]+,\s*|'|\]
```

and remove it with empty string to get your desired string.

As you only want to remove first comma and everything before it, you need `^[^,]+,\s*` and rest you need to also remove all quotes using `'` and `]` with `\]`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mKPRAK/1/)**

As an alternative way, where I assume you originally had your elements in a list, you should preferable use this approach which doesn't depend upon regex to get your intended output.

```
arr = ['lo', 'ens4', 'tun0', 'tun1']
arr.remove('lo')
print(', '.join(arr))
```

Prints your intended output,

```
ens4, tun0, tun1
```

Comment: thank you!! I might have not ever figured that out.

Comment: @mwoolweaver: I've added another solution without using regex as I believe your string indeed was initially a list. You may try using that approach as well.

Comment: what I'm getting is returned from the `netifaces` module which was the "easiest" way to get a list of network infaces? I assume it returns a list as i couldn't manipulate it's output with regex. If you'd like you can see the whole script here on github -> https://github.com/mwoolweaver/tweetStats/blob/master/tweetStats.py

Comment: @mwoolweaver: Yes, indeed `netifaces.interfaces()` returned a list and hence using my second approach is better to use as that way `lo` will be removed irrespective of its position in array. Glad I could help and thanks for accepting my answer.